# Call a random method with random method as parameter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, methods, nested

So, I'm working in a SpawnController for my Unity game. I want to spawn a random enemy type in a random position.

I currently have this two methods for randomizing the spawn position:

From Top of the screen:

```
void SpawnTop(IEnumerator spawnMethod)
{
    //There's 4 positions on plane X where the enemy can spawn
    randomXSpawnSection[0] = Random.Range(-13f, -6.5f);
    randomXSpawnSection[1] = Random.Range(-6.5f, 0f);
    randomXSpawnSection[2] = Random.Range(0f, 6.5f);
    randomXSpawnSection[3] = Random.Range(6.5f, 13.1f);

    StartCoroutine(spawnMethod);
}
```

And from the Side of the screen:

```
void SpawnSide(IEnumerator spawnMethod)
{
    //There's 4 positions on plane Z where the enemy can spawn
    randomZSpawnSection[0] = Random.Range(-7f, 1.5f);
    randomZSpawnSection[1] = Random.Range(1.5f, 10f);
    randomZSpawnSection[2] = Random.Range(10f, 18.5f);
    randomZSpawnSection[3] = Random.Range(18.5f, 27.1f);

    StartCoroutine(spawnMethod);
}
```

Both of this methods use as parameter another method that instantiates a certain type of enemy like this one:

```
IEnumerator SpawnEnemyGunner(float randXSpawn, float randTimeSpawn)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(randTimeSpawn);

    randZSpawn = Random.Range(24, 30);
    Instantiate(enemyGunner, new Vector3(randXSpawn, 1.5f, randZSpawn), enemyGunner.transform.rotation);

    spawning = false;
}
```

I have several enemies in the game therefore several of this methods.

An example of calling the nested methods without randomizing them would be:

```
SpawnTop(SpawnEnemyGunner(Random.Range(0, randomXSpawnSection.Length), Random.Range(3, 6)));
```

I want to randomize the method and his method parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A specific generic approach can look like this:

```
IEnumerator Foo1(float someParam)
        { 
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            Debug.Log($"Foo1: {someParam}");
        }

        IEnumerator Foo2(float someParam2)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            Debug.Log($"Foo2: {someParam}");
        }

        void CallRandomFoo()
        {
            Func<float, IEnumerator>[] foos = { Foo1, Foo2 };
            var randomParam = Random.value;
            StartCoroutine(foos[Random.Range(0, foos.Length)](randomParam));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be as simple as

```
var x = randomXSpawnSection[Random.Range(0, randomXSpawnSection.Length)];
var y = randomZSpawnSection[Random.Range(0, randomZSpawnSection.Length)];
var enemy = Prefabs[Random.Range(0, Prefabs.Length)];

Instantiate(enemy, new Vector3(x, 1.5f, y), enemyGunner.transform.rotation);
```

Comment: In that case I'm just instantiating a random prefab, not what I'm looking for.